# R User Segmentation

Tags: r

I'm looking to group users into segments according to their transaction behavior using R.

```
segment_name        definition
1                   1-2 days since last order, with minimum of 8 unique transaction_id since X date
2                   1-2 days since last order, with less than 8 unique transaction_id since X date OR 3-6 days since last order
3                   7+ days since last order
```

The reason why I put in X date in the above is that I would like to be able to assign a value to that date. Say if I wanted to see how different the segmentation would be if I looked at all their orders within the last 30 days vs last 60 days.

Anyway, I have a table like below:

```
date            user_id     transaction_id
Jan 1, 2018     123         ABC123
Jan 1, 2018     123         DEF456
Jan 2, 2018     123         GHI789
Jan 6, 2018     123         JKL012
Jan 19, 2018    123         MNO345
Jan 20, 2018    123         PQR678
Jan 21, 2018    123         STU901
Jan 26, 2018    123         VWX234
Jan 27, 2018    123         YZA567
```

Based on the rules, I would like to be able to see the user's movement across segments week on week.

```
date (weekly)   user_id     segment_name
Jan 7, 2018     123         2
Jan 14, 2018    123         3
Jan 21, 2018    123         2
Jan 28, 2018    123         1
```

Hope someone can help me figure out how to do this.

EDIT: I made it up to this. I don't know how to turn this to only show the weekly summary and for the rec to show the days since the last transaction date from the weekly date.

```
date            user_id     orders      cumu_orders     rec     date (weekly)
Jan 1, 2018     123         2           2               NA      Jan 7, 2018 
Jan 2, 2018     123         1           3               1       Jan 7, 2018 
Jan 6, 2018     123         1           4               4       Jan 7, 2018 
Jan 19, 2018    123         1           5               13      Jan 21, 2018
Jan 20, 2018    123         1           6               1       Jan 21, 2018
Jan 21, 2018    123         1           7               1       Jan 21, 2018
Jan 26, 2018    123         1           8               5       Jan 28, 2018
Jan 27, 2018    123         1           9               1       Jan 28, 2018
```

Comment: What have you tried? Looks like you should start by calculating the days since each transaction, so you are able to count them to identify your segment.

Comment: I've managed to show me the weekly level, the last date of transaction of that week, and the last cumulative count of transactions for that week. I don't know how to calculate the number of days since the arbitrary week level date, if that makes sense. I can show the days since the last date, but not days since date identified as week of transaction.

Comment: First it is easiest to define extra columns, such as the number of days since a certain date. You can first create a column that defines the week of transaction, then use posix.ct or whatever datetime library you choose to determine days since week level date.

Comment: Thanks for that. I understand it, but I'm really new to R so it would really help if you could write out the code for it.